Implementing a Perl `implies` macro or operator
(I read Writing a macro in Perl, but still need directions)
Eiffel has an implies operator (Implicative boolean operator, see "8.5.20 Syntax: Operators" in ECMA-367, 2nd edition), i.e.

a implies b

meaning

not a or b

So the first attempt was to use
# a implies b (a --> b)
sub implies($$)
{
    return !$_[0] || $_[1];
}

However that's a function, and not an operator.
Specifically the short-cut evaluation fails for cases like

implies(defined($a), $a eq '@')

(resulting in "Use of uninitialized value $a in string eq at ...").
So the question is (for Perl 5.18.2):
Is there an elegant way to add such an "operator" to Perl?

Why do you use perl 5.18 (from 2013) ? I would recommend upgrading to latest version 5.40

The function shortcut is working fine, it is your code outside the function that gives an error.

If you want to avoid errors while composing arbitrary code outside the function, you'll have to dabble in the no warnings pragma, eval, or code references (e.g. sub { $a eq '@' }).

$a//"" eq '@' if it's aesthetically acceptable (may need parens for expression before eq)

@mpapec I thought of that too, the problem is that works for this specific case, but not for arbitrary code. And you do need parens.

defined($a) ? $a eq '@' : 1 and it resembles original

@HåkonHægland Is it relevant for the question or answer? If so, you should have said. Otherwise: Because the code should work in newer Perl versions, too; the opposite might not be true.

@TLK It seems you missed the summary: Of course when implementing it as a function, the parameters will be evaluated. Therefore I was asking for a "macro" or "operator" implementation.

@mpapec Yes, defined($a) ? $a eq '@' : 1 would be possible just as !defined(@a) || $a eq '@', but I wanted some "syntactic sugar".

You could use XS::Parse::Infix::FromPerl.
It provides a way of hooking into Perl's parser to provide a named infix operator. So,

You can introduce the EXPR1 implies EXPR2 syntax, and
you can implement short-circuiting behaviour.

Pragma module: (It's effect is lexically-scoped like use strict;.)
package Syntax::Feature::Implies;

# Usage: `use syntax qw( implies );`
# Provides: `EXPR1 implies EXPR2`

use strict;
use warnings;

use Optree::Generate           qw( newLOGOP newUNOP OP_OR OP_NOT );
use XS::Parse::Infix::FromPerl qw( register_xs_parse_infix XPI_CLS_LOGICAL_OR_MISC );

my $hintkey = __PACKAGE__;

sub import   { $^H{ $hintkey } = 1; }
sub unimport { $^H{ $hintkey } = 0; }

*install   = \&import;    # For syntax.pm
*uninstall = \&unimport;  # For syntax.pm

register_xs_parse_infix(
   implies => (
      cls => XPI_CLS_LOGICAL_OR_MISC,  # Same precedence as `||`.
      permit_hintkey => $hintkey,
      new_op => sub {
         #my ( $flags, $lhs, $rhs, $parsedata, $hookdata ) = @_;
         return newLOGOP( OP_OR, 0,
            newUNOP( OP_NOT, 0, $_[1] ),
            $_[2],
         );
      },
   )
);

1;

Test script:
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use feature qw( say );
use syntax qw( implies );  # Or use Syntax::Feature::Implies;

for my $p ( 0 .. 1 ) {
for my $q ( 0 .. 1 ) {
   my $rhs_evaluated = 0;
   my $r = $p implies do { ++$rhs_evaluated; $q };
   say "$p implies $q = $r  rhs ".( $rhs_evaluated ? "" : "not " )."evaluated";
}}

Output:
0 implies 0 = 1  rhs not evaluated
0 implies 1 = 1  rhs not evaluated
1 implies 0 = 0  rhs evaluated
1 implies 1 = 1  rhs evaluated

I gave it the same precedence as || (untested), but that can be tweaked.



cls
Same precedence as




XPI_CLS_LOGICAL_AND_MISC
&&


XPI_CLS_LOGICAL_OR_MISC
||, ^^, //


XPI_CLS_LOGICAL_AND_LOW_MISC
and


XPI_CLS_LOGICAL_OR_LOW_MISC
or, xor




This does fulfil the elegant qualifier. Very nice.

Nice, yes, but you need to have big knowledge of the Perl internals. Wouldn't it be nice if I could specify in a function prototype that a specific parameter isn't evaluated (in the eval { ... } sense, and not in the eval "..." sense), and you could evaluate the parsed expression then in the sub when needed?

You would have to postpone the evaluation of the expression until inside the subroutine, or hide the errors. For arbitrary code, hiding errors can be hard. But postponing the evaluation by using a code reference will work:
use strict;
use warnings;

sub implies {
    return !($_[0]->()) || $_[1]->();
}

print implies(sub { defined($a) }, sub { $a eq '@' });

Will work as expected. There will be no error, because the second code reference is not executed due to short-circuiting the || operator. This is perhaps not elegant, but I suspect about as elegant as you get without getting considerably more complicated.
It might also work with eval. The evaluation would then depend on the variable being correctly in scope.
sub implies {
    return !(eval $_[0]) || eval $_[1];
}
print implies('defined($a)', q($a eq '@'));


Could do sub implies(&&) { ... } and implies { define $a} => { $a eq '@' } or something like that as well, I suppose? Not sure how to do two blocks following each other.

@simbabque There might be some magic to it, but I seem to recall that there is no way to leave out the sub keyword without using built-in operators (e.g. map, sort etc).

https://metacpan.org/dist/List-MoreUtils/source/lib/List/MoreUtils/PP.pm does it with one sub, but I think it only works with one, not two.

Which sub is that? You linked the whole module

if second argument in prototype can be a function and consistency isn't a thing, pass the first argument as bool, as it always need evaluation unlike second one.

@TLP sorry. most of them have one code argument, so all for example, at the top. But again, it doesn't allow two subs.

@simbabque I see. I never learned much about prototypes. For most code, leaving out the sub keyword would just create a hash reference.

@TLP, You might be interested in my answer.

@ikegami Looks interesting, but unfortunately I don't understand it.

It's a way of hooking into Perl's parser to provide a named infix operator, so 1. you can literally do EXPR1 implies EXPR2 and 2. you get short-circuiting behaviour.

IMHO there is no need to delay evaluating the first parameter.

@U.Windl That's probably not needed, no. Since such an error cannot be avoided anyway.

You can also use Sub::Infix to more simply implement an infix operator, with the caveat that you have to call it with surrounding characters like |, /, etc.
use Sub::Infix;

use strict;
use warnings;

BEGIN { *implies = infix { !$_[0] || $_[1] } };

print (1 |implies| 0);


Are the parentheses around actually needed? The important question is whether evaluation of the parameters is being delayed (e.g.: $a != 0 |implies| 1 / $a > 0 should not cause a "division by zero" error).
